# Can I instance differenct types according to string in golang?

Tags: model-view-controller, go

I want to implement MVC in golang. But it seems like hard to achieve what I want.
in Testcontroller.go I have:

```
func (c *TestController) Test() {
    //
}

func (c *TestController) Index() {
    //
}
```

With only a controller, I can use reflect.ValueOf(TestController{}).MethodByName().Call() to execute that function.
now I want to add another controller. but It seems like I can't new different instance by different string:

```
controllerName := strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")
controller = reflect.ValueOf(controllerName[1])
```

I know this is totaly wrong, but I hope I can get a TestController instance if controllerName == "Test" and get a IndexController instance if controllerName == "Index", using reflect seems can't achieve what I want. Is there any way to do is?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You can always use if;else/switch statement(s).

Comment: That's not a good choice

Comment: I'd use interfaces for it: and interface to identify controllers by name that will allow me to index them in a map or something (although if the number is very low it would be more efficient to simply scan them all). For calling the function you can use reflect.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, Can you give some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like that:

Define an interface for your controllers:

```
type Controller interface {
   // Route returns the root route for that controller
   Route() string
}
```

In a controller just implement it:

```
// this tells our app what's the route for this controller
func (c *TestController) Route() string {
    return "test"
}

func (c *TestController) Test() {
    //
}

func (c *TestController) Index() {
    //
}
```

In our app, create a registry of your controllers, and you can look them up:

```
var controllers = make([]Controller, 0)

// register them somehow
```

And now in the serving process:

```
// assuming the path is /<controller>/<method>
controllerName := strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")

// again, you can use a map here, but for a few controllers it's not worth it probably
for _, c := range controllers {
    if c.Route() == controllerName[1] {

       // do what you did in the single controller example
       callControllerWithReflection(c, controllerName[2])
    }
}
```